# How can I take a photograph via voice control with Google Camera or CyangoenMod default camera?

Tags: camera, photos, voice-command

I know that I can use Google Search and say "OK Google, Take a picture" to open the chosen camera app.

How can I then take a photo? I tried the obvious "snapshot", "take picture" both with and without the prefix  "OK Google".

Comment: CM's camera [had a setting for this](http://androidcommunity.com/cyanogenmod-brings-hands-free-and-voice-shutter-camera-to-android-20130429/) at one point. Have you checked to see if that still exists?

Comment: I have CyanogenMod 11S on a OnePlus One. I see nothing in the settings, and the words that should work "Cheese", "Cid", "Whiskey" seem to do nothing.